# Different digits, commas and periods in text and math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts

In a document I'm using palatino for text (package `newpxtext`) and
euler (package `eulervm`) for math.

If I use the package `eulervm` with no options, the digits, the commas
and the periods in math mode are taken from palatino.

If I use the package `eulervm` with the option `euler-digits`, the digits,
the commas and the periods in math mode are taken from euler.

How, in math mode, can I use the digits from euler and the commas
and the periods from palatino?

Edit: a minimal code showing the differences:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\begin{document}
Text with digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), commas and periods.
Now in math mode, $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add a short compilable code showing what you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

I would make a virtue out of necessity, i.e., I would run the instruction `\useosf` after loading `newpxtext`, so that "old-style" numerals are used in text mode. Incidentally, I would also load the `eulervm` package with the options `small` and `euler-hat-accent`.

Then, use text mode if the numerals do not belong to anything "math-y", and use math mode for numerals that are part of an equation.

I wouldn't bother changing around text-mode and math-mode commas and periods. In math-y material, commas that occur in sequence expressions -- `for $i=1,2,\dots$` -- and in intervals -- `The closed interval $[0,1]$` -- usually don't occur in close proximity to text-mode commas. I doubt any readers would get confused over the two types of commas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext} \useosf % use old-style numerals in text mode
\usepackage[small,euler-digits,euler-hat-accent,T1]{eulervm}

\begin{document}
Text mode: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, \^{a}, \^{c}, \^{z}.

Math mode: $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\hat{a},\hat{c},\hat{z}.$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you suggest using the `small` option with `eulervm`?

Comment: @MHW - Quoting from p. 3 of the package's user guide: "Loading the [eulervm] package with the option `small` causes the Euler fonts to be loaded at 95% of their nominal size, thus blending better with certain text font families, for instance Aldus or Minion." The OP reported that he/she uses Palatino as the text font; Palatino and Aldus are very similar. (Both text fonts were created by Hermann Zapf.)